# How to store 3 different types of data in one array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to store 3 linked bits of data in c. My original thought was a 3 dimensional array but that won't work as all 3 data types are different. The top level needs to be a char array. The second level needs to be a date/time so a integer. The third level is a temperature reading so needs to be a float.

Is the correct way to do this an array of pointers pointing to an array of pointers pointing to a array of floats? If so how would that be written in C?

Comment: how about creating a user-defined data type using `struct`?

Comment: ..or maybe even a union struct?

Comment: so:

struct block
{
    char attributeUid[8];
    int[] time;
    float[] temp;
}; 

and I'd be able to reference each like I would a normal array?

Comment: Are you sure with "*multi-dimensional*"?

Comment: To me your specifications/needs are quite unclear.

Comment: How do you "link bits"?

Comment: There are no associative arrays in C. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)

Comment: @Olaf: The OP means "*bits*" in the sense of "bits&pieces" I suspect.

Comment: @alk: Bad choice of term for a programming question then. But OP seems to be confused about more than that.

Comment: @MichaelOddie have you actually found and followed a C course or tutorial ?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, at uni but I'm used to web programming and I'm currently doing embedded.

Sorry for the use of 'Bits' I understand why that might be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your how you described your data, it sounds like you have a number of timestamped temperature readings for a bunch of named stations/locations/etc, something like

```
Location A           Location B
----------           ----------
time1 -> temp1       time1 -> temp1
time2 -> temp2       time2 -> temp2
   ...                  ...
timeN -> tempN       timeN -> tempN
```

where the timestamps may or may not line up between stations.

Is that close to your situation?

If so, the following model may be useful:

```
struct TimeAndTemp 
{
  time_t timestamp; 
  double temp;
};

struct Station
{
  char name[L+1];                 // L is max name length
  struct TimeAndTemp readings[M]; // M is max readings per station
};

struct Station stations[N]; // array of stations, each station has a name
                            // and contains a list of timestamped
                            // temperature readings.
```

You would access fields like so:

```
strcpy( stations[i].name, newName );
printf( "Station name is %s\n", stations[i].name );
if ( strcmp( stations[i].name, searchName ) == 0 ) { ... }

stations[i].readings[j].timestamp = newTime();
stations[i].readings[j].temp = newTemp();

printf( "Station %s reading at time %s: %f\n",
  stations[i].name, 
  ctime( &stations[i].readings[j].timestamp ),
  stations[i].readings[j].temp );
```

This is a simplistic model that assumes a fixed number of stations and a fixed maximum number of readings per station.  If you wanted something more open-ended you could use linked lists instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A discriminated union, ie a tagged union would possibly be helpful

For eg

```
struct {
    enum { is_int, is_float, is_char } type;
    union {
        int ival;
        float fval;
        char cval;
    } val;
} my_array[10];

The type member is used to hold the choice of which member of the union is should be used for each array element. So if you want to store an int in the first element, you would do:

my_array[0].type = is_int;
my_array[0].val.ival = 3;
```

Comment: So in this case are all three linked? for instance I need to get a "fval" based on the "ival" and "cval".  Is that possible with a tagged union?